# Can not run nosetests when i use argparse in my python code

Tags: python, unit-testing, parsing, command-line, nose

In my main code I have this:

```
  #comp.py
  parser = ArgumentParser()
  parser.add_argument("-n", dest="deg", default=100,type=int, help="setup value of deg")
  parser.add_argument("-k", dest="k", default=25, type=float, help="setup value of k")
  parser.add_argument("-l", dest="l", default=0, type=int, help="setup value of l")
  args = parser.parse_args()

  def afunc(x):
      ...
      #do something with k, l, deg and the return the result
      ...
      return result
```

and my testing file `verify.py`:

```
  #verify.py
  import unittest
  import comp
  class TestFuncs(unittest.TestCase):
      def test_afunc(self):
          self.assertEqual(afunc(0), 0)
          self.assertEqual(afunc(1), 0)
          self.assertEqual(afunc(1), 1)
          self.assertEqual(afunc(3.2), 1)
...
```

And when I tried to run `nosetests` for testing results of function `afunc(...)`, I got this error:

```
machine:project user$ nosetests verify
usage: nosetests [-h] [-n DEG] [-k K] [-l L]
nosetests: error: unrecognized arguments: verify
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you start `nose` exactly? What is name of the file you want to test and what is complete content? (or content as short as possible, but still showing the problem). What do you expect `nose` to do?

Comment: It looks like the ``nosetests`` executable thinks ``verify`` is an argument rather than a file. Perhaps you could give it the full path to your ``verify.py`` file or run nosetests from a more suitable location?

Comment: @JanVlcinsky and Yani Please check my answer it's work for me. If you have any additional ideas please add some answers or put some comments thank you for your help.

Comment: @teces907 Actually, the problem can be much simpler -your call to `nosetests` is passing argument `verify` and it shall be `verify.py`

Comment: @JanVlcinsky thank you very much, sorry for my poor experience with nosetests. Let me check my code before accept you answer.

Comment: @terces907 No need to apologize for poor experience. You are improving it and in fact, it is never ending iterative process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I just solved the problem by adding a few lines of if else condition.

It seems to be my test file (`verify.py`) can not manage value assignment on the parser section in `comp.py`. So, I just add some condition below to assign the values of `deg`, `k`, `l` in case that `comp.py` doesn't run as a main function.

```
#comp.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-n", dest="deg", default=100,type=int, help="setup value of deg")
    parser.add_argument("-k", dest="k", default=25, type=float, help="setup value of k")
    parser.add_argument("-l", dest="l", default=0, type=int, help="setup value of l")
    args = parser.parse_args()
else:
    deg=100
    k=25
    l=0

def afunc(x):
    ...
    #do something with k, l, deg and the return the result
    ...
    return result
```

Answer (score 3):

## Updated `comp.py`

- run the actual code only from `if __name__ == "__main__"` block. This allows safe importing of the module and also running the code, when called as script
- separate argument parsing into `main` function
- keep the tested `afunc` as independent from the rest as possible, so expect all needed input to be passed via arguments, not via `sys.argv` or other global state. This makes your function much more testable

Here comes the code:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

def main():
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-n", dest="deg", default=100,type=int, help="setup value of deg")
    parser.add_argument("-k", dest="k", default=25, type=float, help="setup value of k")
    parser.add_argument("-l", dest="l", default=0, type=int, help="setup value of l")
    args = parser.parse_args()

def afunc(x):
    return 2 * x

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

## Updated `veryfi.py` => `test_it.py`

- call the file `test_(something).py`. Nose will then discover the file automatically.
- define clear focus of your test, in this case ignore the argument parsing and test only the `afunc`
- (recommended) split to smaller test cases - your test run report will tell you much better, what really went wrong.
- (nose feature) use test generator as shown with `test_with_gen`.
- possibly move the test(s) into `tests` subdirectory. Just a habit. And it allows to target `nose` to tests with better precision.

Here is updated `test_it.py`:

```
import unittest
from comp import afunc

class TestFuncs(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_afunc(self):
      self.assertEqual(afunc(0), 0)
      self.assertEqual(afunc(1), 2)
      self.assertEqual(afunc(2), 4)
      self.assertEqual(afunc(3.2), 6.4)

def test_case_0():
    assert afunc(0) == 0

def test_case_1():
    assert afunc(1) == 2

def test_with_gen():
    plan = [(0, 0), (1, 2), (2, 4), (3.2, 6.4)]
    for arg, expected in plan:
        yield check_afunc, arg, expected

def check_afunc(arg, expected):
    assert afunc(arg) == expected
```

Run the test:

```
$ nosetests -v
test_afunc (test_it.TestFuncs) ... ok
test_it.test_case_0 ... ok
test_it.test_case_1 ... ok
test_it.test_with_gen(0, 0) ... ok
test_it.test_with_gen(1, 2) ... ok
test_it.test_with_gen(2, 4) ... ok
test_it.test_with_gen(3.2, 6.4) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 7 tests in 0.005s

OK
```